# Find the limit or prove that the limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim_{x \to c}x^2 + x + 1,$ for any $c \in R$

This is what I tried.

For $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $0< \mid x - c \mid < \delta (x \in R)$ => $\mid x^2 + x + 1 - c^2 - c - 1 \mid = \mid x^2 + x - c^2 - c \mid < \epsilon$

After that I tried to use triangle inequlity $\mid x^2 - c^2 + x - c \mid \leq \mid x^2 - c^2 \mid + \mid x - c \mid$

if $\mid x^2 - c^2 \mid + \mid x - c \mid$ is less then $ \mid x^2 - c^2 + x - c \mid$, I was going to make $\mid x^2 - c^2 \mid + \mid x - c \mid$ to $\mid x + c \mid \mid x- c \mid +\mid x - c\mid$ and then $\mid x - c \mid  \mid x+c\mid +1 \mid$

and then use $\mid x - c \mid \mid x+c\mid +1 \mid < \epsilon  $

However, I cannot 
I am stuck now.

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

Start by choosing $\delta \le |c|+1$, then $|x| \le |c|+|x-c| \le 2(|c|+1)$.

Then $|x^2-c^2| = |x+c||x-c| \le 3 (|c|+1) |x-c|$.

Then $|x^2+x+1 - (c^2+c+1)| \le (3|c|+2)|x-c|$.

Now choose $\delta < \min (|c|, {\epsilon \over 3|c|+2})$, then you will
obain the required bound.

Comment: could you explain about last part ? I am confused about delta minimum things

Comment: We want to choose $\delta$ such that if $|x-c| < \delta$, then the left hand side will be $< \epsilon$. So, I need $\delta <|c|$ so I can use the above bound, then we know that the left hand side is $\le (3|c|+1)|x-c|$. And this will be $< (3|c|+1) \delta$. So, if I choose $\delta$ as I have above, we will have the left hand side $< \epsilon$.

Comment: How about where did you get .. first part..?

Comment: |x|≤|c|+|x−c|≤2|c| this part

Comment: That is just the triangle inequality combined with the assumption that $\delta \le |c|$.

Comment: I fixed my proof, but it makes it harder to follow, I think. Adjust my above comments appropriately.