# $\lim_{x \to c}x^2+x+1$, for any $c \in R$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Find the limit or prove that the limit does not exist.

$\lim_{x \to c}x^2+x+1$, for any $c \in R$.

Let $\delta \le |c|+1$. Then, if $|x-c|<\delta,|x-c|<|c|+1 $. Then, we have

$|x|=|x+c-c|\le |x-c|+|c|<2|c|+1$.

In addition , we have

$|x^2-c^2|=|x+c||x-c|\le (|x|+|c)|x-c|<(3|c|+1)|x-c|$.

Then, for given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta< \min\{|c|+2,\frac {\varepsilon}{3|c|+1}\}$.

Then, if $|x-c|<\delta, $ we have

$|x^2+x+1-c^2-c-1|=|x^2-c^2+x-c|\le |x+c||x-c|+|x-c|=|x-c|(|x+c|+1)\le|x-c|(|x|+|c|+1)<|x-c|(3|c|+1)<\delta(3|c|+1)<\varepsilon. $

Therefore, the limit does exist, and the limit is $c^2+c+1.$

I borrow an idea from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211324/find-the-limit-or-prove-that-the-limit-does-not-exist). I don't understand some explanations here, so I write in similar but different way. Could you check if the proof is okay?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this argument looks good to me!

On proof structure, it's typical to *start* an analysis proof with the line "Let $\epsilon > 0$." and proceed from there, to emphasise that the $\epsilon$ used is arbitrary and cannot depend on anything you choose. On that note, it's often clearer to say *Pick* $\delta$ instead of *Let* $\delta$ for similar reasons, **you** are choosing the $\delta$. Finally, since you have choice of $\delta$, I'd pick it to be a concrete value, $\delta = |c| + 1$. This has the main benefit of ensuring $\delta > 0$ (as sometimes required by the limit definition) and just shows concreteness.

However these are all proof-writing tips, your argument has no issues.